# Playlist from YouTube Live Channel using API

Tags: youtube-data-api, live

I have an application that uses YoutTube API to search videos, channels, playlist ... all that working well but I can't get a reasonable playlist from the Live Channel. A query like (where UC4R8DWoMoI7CAwX8_LjQHig is the proper live channel id)

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?key=[key]&channelId=UC4R8DWoMoI7CAwX8_LjQHig&maxResults=50&part=snippet

returns 8 items of which 7 are garbage and have nothing to do with what you get on the live channel page (https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC4R8DWoMoI7CAwX8_LjQHig). Only the "Featured Live Streams" is correct (and when I get video from that playlist, it's the correct list as well)

Thanks

Actual reponse (expected is in the youtube link)

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#playlistListResponse",
 "etag": "\"XpPGQXPnxQJhLgs6enD_n8JR4Qk/PGP_FpovX1KsZOhAe4--innaNE4\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 8,
  "resultsPerPage": 50
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#playlist",
   "etag": "\"XpPGQXPnxQJhLgs6enD_n8JR4Qk/kW1-C1oUikh3IyLtK9hUbzQnl0s\"",
   "id": "PLU12uITxBEPHl8dr4q9BhPRINfLyVjAWY",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2019-01-24T23:04:32.000Z",
    "channelId": "UC4R8DWoMoI7CAwX8_LjQHig",
    "title": "Democratic Response to State of the Union",
    "description": "",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/IhrFBb3gTWo/default_live.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/IhrFBb3gTWo/mqdefault_live.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/IhrFBb3gTWo/hqdefault_live.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     },
     "standard": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/IhrFBb3gTWo/sddefault_live.jpg",
      "width": 640,
      "height": 480
     },
     "maxres": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/IhrFBb3gTWo/maxresdefault_live.jpg",
      "width": 1280,
      "height": 720
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "Live",
    "localized": {
     "title": "Democratic Response to State of the Union",
     "description": ""
    }
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#playlist",
   "etag": "\"XpPGQXPnxQJhLgs6enD_n8JR4Qk/of3sxCwj88Q-V9bYX_zkeBP_75M\"",
   "id": "PLU12uITxBEPETz20Ie4iFYT_EZaCKsdpi",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2019-01-24T23:01:42.000Z",
    "channelId": "UC4R8DWoMoI7CAwX8_LjQHig",
    "title": "State of the Union",
    "description": "",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/JUCekz5k9E4/default_live.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/JUCekz5k9E4/mqdefault_live.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/JUCekz5k9E4/hqdefault_live.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "Live",
    "localized": {
     "title": "State of the Union",
     "description": ""
    }
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#playlist",
   "etag": "\"XpPGQXPnxQJhLgs6enD_n8JR4Qk/Nt5Y1fYQXsFYZ3TZbNkcakzPVww\"",
   "id": "PLU12uITxBEPGYGDNfvikX90tRyzn7eZh-",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2018-11-06T19:06:45.000Z",
    "channelId": "UC4R8DWoMoI7CAwX8_LjQHig",
    "title": "Election Night Coverage",
    "description": "",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/pvHba1WE8gI/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/pvHba1WE8gI/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/pvHba1WE8gI/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "Live",
    "localized": {
     "title": "Election Night Coverage",
     "description": ""
    }
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#playlist",
   "etag": "\"XpPGQXPnxQJhLgs6enD_n8JR4Qk/vQKgmRlQrEbwNNkxis7_W9sOlGg\"",
   "id": "PLU12uITxBEPF8XZZj4LudutrjxKqh_gtQ",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2018-08-13T15:56:11.000Z",
    "channelId": "UC4R8DWoMoI7CAwX8_LjQHig",
    "title": "Featured Live Streams",
    "description": "",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/_s1sfxe3zck/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/_s1sfxe3zck/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/_s1sfxe3zck/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "Live",
    "localized": {
     "title": "Featured Live Streams",
     "description": ""
    }
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#playlist",
   "etag": "\"XpPGQXPnxQJhLgs6enD_n8JR4Qk/RbBAgFqfGvYAN6b9rfOfIUPNrAY\"",
   "id": "PLU12uITxBEPFcmBzhqA_w3_SAfcGCbUIp",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2018-05-18T17:58:37.000Z",
    "channelId": "UC4R8DWoMoI7CAwX8_LjQHig",
    "title": "The Royal Wedding",
    "description": "",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/N42MQJX4KoY/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/N42MQJX4KoY/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/N42MQJX4KoY/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     },
     "standard": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/N42MQJX4KoY/sddefault.jpg",
      "width": 640,
      "height": 480
     },
     "maxres": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/N42MQJX4KoY/maxresdefault.jpg",
      "width": 1280,
      "height": 720
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "Live",
    "localized": {
     "title": "The Royal Wedding",
     "description": ""
    }
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#playlist",
   "etag": "\"XpPGQXPnxQJhLgs6enD_n8JR4Qk/rl0pUnKm2ddu0YveTBYRKgSysNI\"",
   "id": "PLU12uITxBEPEjt5-ijGeP_UcVM_RvFr1p",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2018-04-13T22:30:05.000Z",
    "channelId": "UC4R8DWoMoI7CAwX8_LjQHig",
    "title": "Coachella 2018",
    "description": "",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "http://s.ytimg.com/yts/img/no_thumbnail-vfl4t3-4R.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "http://s.ytimg.com/yts/img/no_thumbnail-vfl4t3-4R.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "http://s.ytimg.com/yts/img/no_thumbnail-vfl4t3-4R.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "Live",
    "localized": {
     "title": "Coachella 2018",
     "description": ""
    }
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#playlist",
   "etag": "\"XpPGQXPnxQJhLgs6enD_n8JR4Qk/lgIUABP5PW7-bCHyVOpPkXxCt6Y\"",
   "id": "PLU12uITxBEPGPUMSYceO0ywrY63AOqTU7",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2018-04-13T22:30:05.000Z",
    "channelId": "UC4R8DWoMoI7CAwX8_LjQHig",
    "title": "Coachella 2018",
    "description": "",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "http://s.ytimg.com/yts/img/no_thumbnail-vfl4t3-4R.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "http://s.ytimg.com/yts/img/no_thumbnail-vfl4t3-4R.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "http://s.ytimg.com/yts/img/no_thumbnail-vfl4t3-4R.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "Live",
    "localized": {
     "title": "Coachella 2018",
     "description": ""
    }
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#playlist",
   "etag": "\"XpPGQXPnxQJhLgs6enD_n8JR4Qk/rjBqMP7cQCCrlypBDI4uLoP7IJk\"",
   "id": "PLU12uITxBEPF6MjThhpt24z9kpQGLcO7J",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2018-04-13T22:30:05.000Z",
    "channelId": "UC4R8DWoMoI7CAwX8_LjQHig",
    "title": "Coachella 2018",
    "description": "",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "http://s.ytimg.com/yts/img/no_thumbnail-vfl4t3-4R.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "http://s.ytimg.com/yts/img/no_thumbnail-vfl4t3-4R.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "http://s.ytimg.com/yts/img/no_thumbnail-vfl4t3-4R.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "Live",
    "localized": {
     "title": "Coachella 2018",
     "description": ""
    }
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Can you add the results of this request and the expect results?

Comment: After your update *(and if I understand you correctly)*, do you want retrieve only the results from "Featured Live Streams"?

Comment: No no, the query is for the channel UC4R8DWoMoI7CAwX8_LjQHig (main YT live channel) which normally points to various playlists, "featured live streams" being one of them. You can see that when you access the link through your web browser. But when I'm querying the list of items for the same channel, but using the API, I ony have returned the "featured live streams" which is just the first playlist, and then a serie of "garbage" playlists.

Comment: philippe_44, if you want get the videos from the "Featured Live Streams", you have to use another API call *"by passing the `playlistId` of the mentioned playlist*. This is the `playlistId` of "Featured Live Streams": `PLU12uITxBEPF8XZZj4LudutrjxKqh_gtQ`. Here is a [demo](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%22snippet%2CcontentDetails%22%2C%22maxResults%22%3A10%2C%22playlistId%22%3A%22PLU12uITxBEPF8XZZj4LudutrjxKqh_gtQ%22%7D#examples).

Comment: Thanks for responding, but sorry, I don't understand. I want all the playlists of the channel UC4R8DWoMoI7CAwX8_LjQHig, hence the API call I'm making. It works for all other channel that I identify through their id. Then, later, I'll get the videos of the playlist that the user chooses by doing a playListItems query. This iswhat I do for all other channels, it just does not seem to work for this channel only

Comment: you're right. that behavior is because either because generated YouTube channels aren't treated in the same way other non-generated channels or the API is outdated. The API itself has some undocumented limitations.